# Populate a column via multi-dimensional lookup in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, vlookup

I have the following two tables:

TABLE_A:

| Date | USD | EUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | 1.11 | 0.89 |
| 2020-02-28 | 1.15 | 0.93 |

TABLE_B:

| Date | Currency | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | USD | NULL |
| 2020-02-29 | EUR | NULL |

I want to populate the Amount field in TABLE_B with the corresponding amount in TABLE_A dependent on the matching date and currency. Is there a way to perform this multi-dimensional lookup in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The only join I can see that is common to both tables is the date value, you can join on that and then use a `CASE` expression to choose the appropriate value from `tableA` based on the value in `tableB`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.Currency = 'USD' THEN a.USD ELSE a.EUR END as [Amount]
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b
ON b.Date = a.Date
```

Comment: `CASE` **expression**.